# Newly created Azure Data Factory v2 has no managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-managed-identity

I have created a new Azure Data Factory v2 resource with the below Azure CLI command:

```
az datafactory factory create --location "North Europe" --name $DataFactoryName --resource-group $DataFactoryResourceGroup
```

The resource was created successfully but no Managed Identity was assigned to the Data Factory as it was with previously created data factory resources.

[image]

I also confirmed that there is no Managed Identity with the below command

```
az datafactory factory show --name $DataFactoryName --resource-group $DataFactoryResourceGroup
```

{
"additionalProperties": null,
"createTime": "2020-11-05T09:13:43.243343+00:00",
"eTag": ""5c01dfcc-0000-0c00-0000-5fa3c2470000"",
"globalParameters": null,
"id": XXXXXX
**"identity": null,**
"location": "northeurope",
"name": XXXXXX
"provisioningState": "Succeeded",
"repoConfiguration": null,
"resourceGroup": XXXXXX,
"tags": {},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
"version": "2018-06-01"
}

Any idea how I can enable the Managed Identity for the Data Factory and why it was not automaticcaly created as [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/datafactory/datafactory/factory?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_datafactory_az_datafactory_factory_create) does not appear to have an options to create it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks there is no option to enable the Managed Identity when creating it with `az datafactory factory create`, you could enable the Managed Identity with the command below after creating.

```
az resource update --name <factoryname> --resource-group <group-name> --namespace Microsoft.DataFactory --resource-type factories --set identity.type=SystemAssigned
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Joy Wang. Fixed my issue